# How to get the multiple value without select tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to take multiple checkbox values, I tried bit I can't get why means here select and option not there , I tried to do that this way but I am unable to get the value

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" id="property_type2" name="property_type2" role="menu" style="color:#333;width:315px;height: 102px;border-radius:0px;" >
 <div class="chkbox" style="padding-left:5px;">
  <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-success">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="flat"> Flat
  </label>
  
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="villa"> House/Villa
  </label>
  
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="plot"> Plot
  </label>
  
 </div>
</div>

     var foo = []; 
  $('.chkbox :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
  });
       console.log(foo);
```

Comment: There may be other issues, but certainly your selector .chkbox does not match any elements.  Add class='chkbox' to the html for the checkbox elements and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for - https://jsfiddle.net/sekrars9/

```js
$("#btnGetValues").click(function() {
    
      var foo = [];
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        foo.push($(this).val());
      });
      alert(foo.join(","));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" id="property_type2" name="property_type2" role="menu" style="color:#333;width:315px;height: 102px;border-radius:0px;">
      <div class="chkbox" style="padding-left:5px;">
        <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-success">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="flat"> Flat
        </label>
    
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="villa"> House/Villa
        </label>
    
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="plot"> Plot
        </label>
        <input type="button" id="btnGetValues" value="Get Values">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following HTML will work as per your need :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.each($('input'),function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            console.log($(this).val());
       });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" id="property_type2" name="property_type2" role="menu" style="color:#333;width:315px;height: 102px;border-radius:0px;" >
    <div class="chkbox" style="padding-left:5px;">
        <label class="checkbox-inline checkbox-success">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="flat"> Flat
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="villa"> House/Villa
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="Check3" value="plot"> Plot
        </label>

    </div>
</div>

 </body>

</html>
```